# Profile: top tags numbers are inconsistent

Tags: bug, profile-page, android-app, ios-app

On the website, the top tags number only shows your answer score, whereas on the apps it shows the combined score of questions+answers. This is pretty confusing.

Comment: If you've tagged this as a [bug], it's probably [status-bydesign], but if you want to suggest a change, you might want to retag as [feature-request].

Comment: It's more of a bug-by-design, but alas: no tag.

Comment: FWIW, this is the same in the iOS app.