# What do the numbers to the left and right of my tags mean?

Tags: support, tags, profile-page, ios-app, mobile-app

I looked at my tags section and saw two numbers without an explanation.

[image]

I'm guessing one of these is tag score, and that is what I'm looking for to see my progress towards a tag badge.

Is there an explanation for what the numbers mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **number on the left** is total tag score (=score on answers + score on questions). This is different from the score on [your profile page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/145171/haykam?tab=tags) on the main site, which only shows the total answer score. (See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243048/266359) and [its duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212299/266359) for more information about that discrepancy.)

The **number on the right** is the total number of posts (questions and answers) in that tag.

Comment: Is there a way to find the tag score used by tag badges?

Comment: Yes. That score is your answer score, which is shown on your profile page when viewed in a web browser.

Comment: Isn't that the total score for all tags? I'm just looking at one tag.

Comment: There's also a minimum number of answers requirement for tag badges.

Comment: @haykam he means [this page](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/145171/haykam?tab=tags)

Comment: @haykam Right, but if you're looking at your numbers in the app, you will see a number that includes the votes on your questions

Comment: @Shokhet That includes questions and answers. Tag badges only count total score for answers.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thank you for the better link. Editing my answer now

Comment: @haykam If you view the count in the app, it will include questions and answers. If you look [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/145171/haykam?tab=tags) in a browser (and not in the Stack Exchange app), then the number shown on the left corresponds to *answer* score, without counting votes on questions

Comment: That's dumb. Couldn't they just have both?

Comment: @haykam I don't know which way is better; I just find it confusing that the number on the left means different things on the web and in the app. I think that whatever the number is, it should have a consistent meaning. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243048/266359 and the linked duplicate

Answer (score 3):

The number on the left is your score in the tag, the number on the right is the number of posts that you've made that reference that tag.

Comment: Looks like you were ninja'd with [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292296/318692) from [Shokhet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/266359/shokhet). I'm giving acceptance to their answer, but I'll still upvote yours.